# Difference between session handling locally and on server with Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I am using sessions and have enabled sessions in my GAE app

```
<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
<async-session-persistence enabled="true" />
```

I am using sessions for the purpose of a simple user login. Locally, this works just fine, my session is maintained until I logout and all my pages that are "protected" are viewable with a valid session.

The problem with my live/production server on appspot is that it doesn't work at all. When I login and authenticate, I redirect to another page. This page checks if I have a valid session (using standard HttpSession) and somehow this fails and then redirects me back to the login screen.

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work in the GAE production environment but works just fine locally?

Here is the code I use to check validity of current session:

```
public static boolean isValidSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (request.isRequestedSessionIdValid());
}
```

**Update:**
I'm creating session ID like this:

```
public static void createNewSession(HttpServletRequest request, final String username) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("username", username);
    }
```

Comment: How do you set the session ID?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, added the code for session ID.

Comment: session handling, you mean?

Comment: @Momergil, fixed that typo, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between handling sessions locally and in production as such on Google App Engine. They work the same in both the environment. The only difference that I can think of is that when you create sessions (say at or after Login) locally and you set some attribute in the session say the access level of the user, it will not change even when attribute's value change(say if it is pulled dynamically from some database where it got changed after Login) until you close the tab and Login again, however in production if the attribute changes in the database and then if you refresh the page it will take the new value from the database. Well that's in my experience.  Hope it helps.